# open gl drawing a line error?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define ROUND(a) ((int)+.5)

void display(void) {    
    int xa = 10, ya = 3, xb = 56, yb = 98;
    int dx = xb - xa, dy = yb - ya, steps, k;
    float xincre, yincre, x = xa, y = ya;
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    if (abs(dx) > abs(dy))
        steps = abs(dx);
    else
        steps = abs(dy);
    xincre = dx / (float)steps;
    yincre = dy / (float)steps;

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2s(ROUND(x), ROUND(y));
    for (k = 0; k < steps; k++) {
        x += xincre;
        y += yincre;
        glVertex2s(ROUND(x), ROUND(y));
        printf("%f,%f", x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("CpViewer");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to implement the dda algorithm 
for making  a line but it seems just to print a 
point . i am not able to understand where is the problem ?
i only get a blue point as the output in the white background

Comment: You should use the standard `round` function instead of a macro (!) that doesn't work properly for certain valid inputs. In fact, your macro doesn't even round anything. At least with a function, that'd be a compiler warning.

Comment: Your `ROUND` macro doesn't even use `a`. Did you mean `((int)((a)+.5))`?

Comment: yeah i corrected it   #define ROUND(a) ((int)(a+.5)) but still the same output

Comment: @Hari, That's not even corrected. Even ignoring the fact that certain corner cases will give flat out wrong results, other [normal cases](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e216b41511fb3af9) won't even compile.

Comment: @chris i did use the round function but i think that error is somewhere else

Comment: I wonder why this would draw a blue point - it clearly should draw nothing, since you are drawing completely outside of the viewing volume.

Answer (score 1):

The drawing coordinates are defined in terms of a normalized rectangle (x and y each between -1 and 1), not in terms of window coordinates. So, the left-most x coordinate for drawing is 0 in window coordinates and -1.0 in drawing coordinates, and the right-most x coordinate is the window width (500 in this case) in window coordinates, and 1.0 in drawing coordinates. The y-coordinates are the same, but the y-axis is flipped from window coordinates to drawing coordinates (-1 in drawing coordinates would be 500 in window coordinates).

Try drawing the points with glVertex2f and rescaling the points by the window size:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (k = 0; k <= steps; k++) {
    glVertex2f((x - 250.f)/250.f, (250.f - y)/250.f);
    printf("%f,%f", x, y);
    x += xincre;
    y += yincre;
}
glEnd();
```

You'll also need to keep track of if the window gets resized, to make sure that you're scaling these coordinates correctly, but for the moment, this should work.